# Ionic. Return factory from data from JSON file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-http

I'm playing around with Ionic sample projects and am looking for a way to pull in the data from a json file rather than just the standard array that is in the project.

I have successfully modified services.js to grab the data from the JSON but my template does not get the data. I assume this is because it executes before the http request for the JSON has completed.

What do I need to do to make this work?

```
........
.factory('People', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
  var people = $http.get('../data/peopleData.json').success(function(response){
    console.log(response.people); //the data is correctly logged
    return response.people;
  });

  // var people = [{
  //   id: 0,
  //   name: 'Kassiopi'
  // }, {
  //   id: 1,
  //   name: 'Imerola Bay'
  // }];
  //original and works great
return {
    all: function() {
      return people;
    },

    get: function(personId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (people[i].id === parseInt(people)) {
          return people[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.people = People.all();
```

Comment: Plesae share how you are accessing it in controller ?

Comment: @mudasserajaz Updated my post :)

Comment: @Fraser ever looked at mine answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not getting in controller because data is being fetched after  `$scope.people = People.all();` is executed as you are making async call here. So use defer from `$q` service of angular.

```
.factory('People', function($http, $q) {
     var people = function () {
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '../data/peopleData.json'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deffered.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deffered.reject(status);
        });

        return deffered.promise;
      };
```

And change in factory return

```
  return {
    all: people,
```

Now `people` will return you promise in controller , from which you can get data this way

```
 var peoplePromise =  People.all();
 peoplePromise.then(function(response){
  $scope.people = response; //assign data here to your $scope object
},function(error){
  console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: `$http` does return an promise..is that `$q.defer()` overhead needed..?

Comment: Well There is a downside of blindly passing  $http.get promise to the controller, that the controller has to deal with the result itself. It helps when you  want the service to post-process the result instead. More importantly  to deal with the $http errors in the service layer, so that the controller doesn't need to handle redirects, 404s, etc

Comment: That you could be done by using promise chaining..I don't think so custom promise needed there..

Comment: @mudasserajaz thank you for the time with your post, however this gives me 'peoplePromise.then is not a function'

Comment: @Fraser sorry i forgot to mention, you need to change in factory return, i added it in my answer. In return you need to write this way `all: people`

Comment: @Fraser I am glad it helped :)

Comment: Thank you so very much for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you wanted to return data from your service `Harbours`, and you are using callback on the ajax and trying to return data from the callback is main threat in your current code.
In your factory you need to return the `$http.get` function which has promise, when the ajax gets completed it does call the `.then` function which has `response` which contains `data`, `status`, `headers` & `statusText`. For accessing data you could do use `response.data` & do return it from the service.

**Factory**

```
.factory('Harbours', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
  var people = return $http.get('../data/peopleData.json').then(function(response){
    data = response.data;
    console.log(data.people); //the data is correctly logged
    return data.people;

  });

  return {
     all: function() {
        return people;
     },
     //other code here
  };
});
```

Your current code has `$scope.people = People.all();` which is nothing but assigning `People.all()` which does nothing this is not how `promises` & `async` call work. You need to do follow below step and code to get your code working.

For getting access to data from a controller you need to again use `.then` function on your service `people` method which returns a `promise`. Basically the controller `.then` function will get called once the data

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(Harbours, $scope){
   //this will call people of Harbours service
   //.then function will get call once the people function, 
   //resolves its promise and return a data
   Harbours.all().then(function(data){ //success callback
       console.log(data); //you will have your data here.
       $scope.people = data;
   },function(error){ //error callback
       console.log(error);//error occurred here
   })
})
```

I'd suggest you to read up [**How Promises work**](https://masteringmean.com/lessons/633-AngularJS-Promises)